# Additional Firebase Reads

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore query which in my case should read 'n' documents. However it always ends up reading "n x 2" documents.

Have experienced the same problem while reading collection once or on using a snapshot listner.

Any thoughts on why and how to prevent such reads.

```
 datastore.collection("PlatformData/CollatedData/Inventory").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log(querySnapshot)
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         //doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
         console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
   });
```

On further trials, I observed that

```
datastore.collection("PlatformData").doc("CollatedData").collection("Inventory").get().then((snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot) });
```

although being the method provided in firebase docs reads documents n x 2 times while as

```
datastore.collection("PlatformData").doc("CollatedData").collection("Inventory").get();
```

reads the documents n times.

Comment: Are you sure you are not reading documents twice some where else in the code? Also the reads shown in console may not be realtime. Not sure if this [issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1460) is relevant

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that because to test this theory out I wrote some code whose only job is to read that one collection. And irrespective of how many documents I keep in that collection, the read operations are always twice the number of documents.

Comment: Tried the 'includeMetadataChanges' implementation as well. No luck. Neither with the servertimestamp because there arent any server timestamps on this data.

Comment: @Dharmaraj:
On further trials, I observed that

datastore.collection("PlatformData").doc("CollatedData").collection("Inventory").get().then((snapshot) => { console.log(snapshot) });
although being the method provided in firebase docs reads documents n x 2 times while as

datastore.collection("PlatformData").doc("CollatedData").collection("Inventory").get();
reads the documents n times

Comment: What's the difference in them? The queries look same to me.

Comment: The one with the 2x reads uses .then function to read the query result.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Whether you use  .then() or async-await that shouldn't affect the reads.